# Difference with TransisitionWithView and AnimationWithDuration

Tags: ios, animation

I can pretty much do everything TransistionWithView can do with AnimationWithDuration.  I'm really not sure when there is a use case to just one over the other.

What are the use case to use TransitionWithView over AnimateWithDuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[UIView transitionWithView:]` allows animating actions that aren't restricted to modifying values of animatable properties. For example:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                  duration:0.2
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{ [fromView removeFromSuperview]; [containerView addSubview:toView]; }
                completion:NULL];
```

This allows you to animate the addition, removal, showing, or hiding of subviews where `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` only animates value changes for animatable properties.

Comment: They do. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

Comment: I meant the difference

Comment: Wait then your anwser is not fully correct, why would apple create two completely different api just because of this difference?

Comment: Because they are for fundamentally different things. One is meant to animate transitions between views and the other is intended to animate properties of views.